# How do I stop sonar running tests?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm looking at using Sonar to reduced the number of plugins I've had to install in Jenkins to get some decent code analysis (and sonar seems to do more and present it better).  However when I kick of the sonar job the JUnit / Concordion tests are executed.  I don't want these tests run as Jenkins is already executing the tests.

How do I stop the tests executing and just perform code analysis?

I've installed sonar 3.7.3 and executing using the Gradle sonar-runner plugin and specifying the :sonarRunner task.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just facing the same issue and it seems that you can run `:sonarqube -x test` to avoid having tests run before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `sonar.dynamicAnalysis` property to `false`. This will skip tests and only perform the static analysis part.

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-OptionalParameters

Comment: I added the property to build.gradle settings but it didn't seem to make a difference:  
  
sonarRunner {  
 sonarProperties {  
  property "sonar.host.url", "http://xxxxx/sonar"  
  property "sonar.jdbc.url",  "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxxx/SonarQube;instance=SQLEXPRESS;SelectMethod=Cursor"  
  property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName",  "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"  
  property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonarqube"  
  property "sonar.jdbc.password", "xxxxx"  
  property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "false"  
 }  
}