# How do I stop the maven sonar plugin from running tests?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I've got a two stage CI-pipeline with the first stage running compile and test, and the second stage running the maven [sonar](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) plugin.

I'm using this maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sonar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm sending the following parameters to my maven command:

```
-DskipTests=true
```

This has no effect. (ie it stops maven from triggering the tests, but then the sonar plugin triggers them all over again).

My question is: **How do I stop the maven sonar plugin from running tests?**

Note - I believe this is different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555535/how-do-i-stop-sonar-running-tests) (ie not a duplicate) because this is maven and that question is gradle.

Comment: I don't understand your config. The `sonar-maven-plugin` does not have a `package` goal. What do you want to skip, tests or code analysis dony by the `sonar:sonar` goal? Can you share you build log to see what exactly happens and which goals you want to skip?

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. I’ve updated the question.

Comment: `mvn sonar:sonar` doesn't run the tests. It must be triggered by another goal. What's the complete `mvn` command you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try `-Dsonar.skip=true`

As per the plugin documentation for `sonar:sonar` goal:

> **sonar:sonar**
>   Description: Analyze project. SonarQube server must be started.
>   Implementation: org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo
>   Language: java
>
> Available parameters:
>
> ```
> skip (Default: false)
>   User property: sonar.skip
>   Set this to 'true' to skip analysis.
> ```

Comment: Thanks - but I don’t want to skip the information being uploaded to sonar - I already have the Jacoco exec file. I just want to run sonar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar [CI setup](https://bitbucket.org/borisredkin/java-header-updater/src/ff158ec6a348a065e11bc820acf9712a527d5916/bitbucket-pipelines.yml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) for my project. But I don't use *sonar-maven-plugin*. Instead I run a maven goal: *sonar:sonar* in the directory where the pom.xml file exisits:

```
$ mvn sonar:sonar
```

and this does not execute unit tests.

This is taken from the [official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-AnalyzingaMavenProject) on Analyzing a Maven Project with SonarQube.